# Extracting Audio Data from MP3/MIDI file

Tags: java, android, mp3, midi

I want to make games that use "audio events" ( I don't know how to say it correctly) in that MP3/MIDI file. For example in MIDI, i need to extract keyboard event. The problem is that I really don't know what the representation of that event in any audio formats. Is there anybody here know what it is ?

NB: I googled around about MIDI file formats then i found good information at http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/midifiles.html but still dunno what information that i want to extract from MIDI file.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear, and MP3/MIDI files have absolutely nothing to do with each other.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://code.google.com/p/android-midi-lib/) could be a starting point `android-midi-lib`

> This project is mainly for use with Android applications that do not have access to Java's javax.sound.midi library. However, it is a stand-alone Java library with no Android-specific dependencies or considerations.
>
> This code provides an interface to read, manipulate, and write MIDI files. "Playback" is supported as a real-time event dispatch system.

Frankly I'm not clear about your question, here is [the Midi Events code](http://code.google.com/p/android-midi-lib/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/com/leff/midi/event%253Fstate%253Dclosed)

Answer (score 0):

here I'm providing the info for extract metadata from Mp3 file with example.

!pip install audio_metadata

import pandas as pd

import audio_metadata #import library

## extract metadata from Mp3 file

metadata = audio_metadata.load('DJ Snake - Let Me Love You ft. Justin Bieber.mp3')

## To extract specific tags from metadata

dict1 = {"Title":metadata.tags.title}

## export data to 'csv' file

pd.DataFrame(dict1).to_csv('samplz.csv')